# How to place object randomly on Different angle and different position python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to make a function which generate a dataset, The object will be place on the black image at different position with different angle, different size and place randomly maximum up to 20 time in image. and Save the x,y and angle position in the text file.

[image: Input image]

The following image is for five objects at different position and angle.

[image: Output image for five objects]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
patch=cv2.imread('imagersult.png')
img = np.zeros((2048, 2048, 1), dtype = "uint8")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can use the [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) module to rotate your patches:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from random import randrange
from scipy import ndimage

def patch_img(img, patch, amt=5):
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    for _ in range(amt):
        p = ndimage.rotate(patch, randrange(360))
        p_h, p_w, _ = p.shape
        x = randrange(w - p_w)
        y = randrange(h - p_h)
        seg = img[y: y + p_h, x: x + p_w]
        seg[:] = cv2.bitwise_xor(seg, p)

patch = cv2.imread('imagersult.png')

img = np.zeros((2048, 2048, 3), dtype="uint8")
patch_img(img, patch)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Outputs for multiple runs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For grayscale and variation in size of the patches:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from random import randrange, uniform
from scipy import ndimage

def patch_img(img, patch, amt=5):
    h, w = img.shape
    min_scale = 0.5
    max_scale = 2
    for _ in range(amt):
        patch_h, patch_w = patch.shape
        scale = uniform(min_scale, max_scale)
        p = ndimage.rotate(cv2.resize(patch, (int(patch_w * scale), int(patch_h * scale))), randrange(360))
        p_h, p_w = p.shape
        x = randrange(w - p_w)
        y = randrange(h - p_h)
        seg = img[y: y + p_h, x: x + p_w]
        seg[:] = cv2.bitwise_xor(seg, p)

patch = cv2.imread('imagersult.png', 0)

img = np.zeros((2048, 2048), dtype="uint8")
patch_img(img, patch)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: i wanted it for grayscale, it gives the following error                                                               img = np.zeros((2048, 2048, 1), dtype = "uint8")
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:229: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'binary_op'

Comment: is it possible I can say 500 generated image in a folder, with a text file in which position and angle will be saved

Comment: Can we vary the object size randomly like small to large?

Comment: thanks it works, Can we also draw the object randomly like amt=5, it can generate the object randomly up to 5

Comment: @AspLab Simply change the `range(amt)` to `range(random.randrange(amt + 1))`.